# Compare and Count Variable Dates?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Using the given statement below I am Receiving the Value of **Course end date** which is in varchar and coming from MySQL I tried to convert this to date format in **$ced & $newformat**...all goes fine but when I am trying to compare course end date with the current date it's not comparing... it's only comparing the date and not comparing with year and month

```
 $enddate = $get_students_row['course_end_date'];
 $ced = strtotime("$enddate");
 $newformat = date('d/m/Y',$ced);
 $currentdate = date('d/m/Y');
```

The function is if $newformat is less than and eqals to current date then field become red

```
<tr <?php if(($newformat <= $currentdate)): ?> style="color:red;" <?php endif; ?>>
```

But its not working as excepted its make row red but its only comapring with current date not with month and year...**.Also i was looking for to get Total count of $newformat.**

My Code

```
                <tr <?php if(($ced <= time())): ?> style="color:red;" <?php endif; ?>>

                   <td><?php  echo $students_rollno_class;?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $students_admission_no;?> </td>
                   <td><?php  echo $students_firstname;?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $students_contact;?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $students_reference_no;?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($students_date));?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $newformat;?></td>



               </tr><?php
                    }
                   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$newformat` and `$currentdate` are just simple strings for PHP. And comparing two strings would not give the answer you expect. So it's better to use UNIX time format.

try this:

```
<tr <?php if(($ced <= time())){ 
   $totalCount++;
   echo 'style="color:red;" ';
<?php } ?>>
```

My `<tr>` Code

```
 <tr <?php if(($ced <= time())): ?> style="color:red;" <?php endif; ?>>
     <td><?php  echo $students_rollno_class;?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $students_admission_no;?> </td>
     <td><?php  echo $students_firstname;?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $students_contact;?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $students_reference_no;?></td>
     <td><?php  echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($students_date));?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $newformat;?></td>
 </tr><?php } ?>
```

Comment: Great Bro....Working good .....can you please help me to resolve the last query which is how can I get total count $ced which is lesser than time

Comment: What do mean by total count? Do you run this in a loop?

Comment: yes after running this the <td> fields showing course end date and after given your code it starts making <td> row red and comparing accurately with time... I was looking also looking for to get total no. of count which become red

Comment: So it Means if i do  $count =  $totalCount++;then i can echo that count anywhere and its also giving error of <?php } ?>

Comment: No. This is not a good practice. Use one of these statements:

$totalCount ++;

or 

$totalCount=$totalCount+1 ;

Both are equivalent and you can print $totalCount after ending the lopp.

Comment: this code becoming all rows red  <tr <?php if(($ced <= time())){ 
   $totalCount++;
   echo 'style="color:red;" ';
<?php } ?>> When i Implement it

Comment: Check your $ced s. Probably time() exceeds all of them.

Comment: Roll back to previous version and check if it goes fine. There is nothing wrong with this if statement.

Comment: Edit this line:
$ced = strtotime("$enddate"); to $ced = strtotime($enddate);

Comment: done using the previous one and try to configuring that how can i get total count

Comment: With IF Statement its giving < unexpected syntax error and if i delete<?php then its not working

Comment: add this statement in the 1st line of your loop:

<?php if(($ced <= time())){ $totalCount++} ?>

Comment: I Added the <tr> Code in Answer

Comment: i added my all code in the answer which is working fine for changing color but not working with count++ but when I try to add modified code which is given above will not work for showing the total count

Answer (score 0):

**You can see the comparison in this national format**

```
$format = "d_m_y";
$date1  = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, "03_01_12");
$date2  = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, "31_12_11");

var_dump($date1 > $date2);
```

**Using DateTime::createFromFormat**:

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#timeTable tr td').each(function () {
    var dtTd = new Date($(this).html());
    var dtNew = new Date();
    // 15 minutes is 900000 milliseconds
   
    if (dtTd.getTime() - dtNew.getTime() < 900000 && dtNew < dtTd) {
        $(this).parent('tr').addClass('min15');
    } else {
        if (dtNew > dtTd) {
            $(this).parent('tr').addClass('old');
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.old {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="timeTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>02/07/2015 23:15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>03/09/2015 11:16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>18/02/2020 11:30</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```